# How to refresh the page with updated data when click update button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, reload

```
function update(){

            var name= document.getElementById("TextBox").value;

$.ajax({
                            url: '....',
                            type: 'post',                               
                            data: {....//many data include// 'name' : name, ....},

                            success: function(data) {

                            var replacevalue=data.replace(/[\[\]']/g,'' );
                            alert(replacevalue);

                            var stringstatus=replacevalue.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
                            alert(stringstatus);                                

                            if(stringstatus == "success"){
                                alert ("Successfully Update ")                                                                          
                            }

                            else{
                                    alert("Failed!");
                                    return ;
                            }

                            returnToDisplayPage();


                        },                              

                            error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                            console.log(xhr);
                            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
                            }
                });


    }

    function returnToDisplayPage(){
        var id = document.getElementById("TextBox").text;
        window.location = './DisplayPage.php?Name='+id;

    }
```

Please suggest me. How should I do to get the updated data when click update button and refresh or reload page ? In function returnToDisplayPage() methods. I got only the name of update data and other related fields data didn't get back.

Comment: simple reload the page in ajax success function like this  window.location.reload();

Comment: @JYoThI, I tried alrdy but it didn't work too.

Comment: can you use Jquery in app?if u can then, on call of function you can reload only particular div.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$.post('url', {params}, function(response){
    //Here you check if you got response from url
    // And then you can do whatever you like to do with received data
    if(response == 'ok'){
     //do your stuff
     //then
     window.location.reload();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we will get result in response then After 5 seconds page will be refresh..

```
success: function(data){
   if(data.success == true){ // if true (1)
      setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
           location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
      }, 5000); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)